# find the column with lowest value in r

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have large size matrix and try to find the column that has the minimum value for each row. For instance, here is my matrix, (simply generate with `matrix(sample(12),nrow = 3)`). With the matrix I want to to have a vector `(3,4,1)` representing the column number which contains the lowest value in each row. 
How should I do it? It could be duplicated question but I could not find answers.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   11    1   12
[2,]    8    9    7    3
[3,]    2    5    6    4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `max.col`:

```
max.col(-mat)
# [1] 3 4 1
```

Comment: I did not know there is such a nice function. Thank you!